# IE10 rendering artifacts

Tags: image, windows-8, rendering, internet-explorer-10, artifacts

I'm testing [my website](http://www.raditaz.com) in IE10 on Windows 8 and I keep getting a bunch of rendering artifacts around or above certain elements. Here's a screenshot (note the black bar):

[image]

The artifacts appear inconsistently – they'll flicker on and off as I interact with the page – but always in the same places, across refreshes.

I'm running Windows 8 in Parallels on a Mac, so my initial hunch was that it was a video card driver issue, but no other browser in Windows 8 exhibits these artifacts. Wouldn't a driver issue affect all browsers the same way?

Comment: Jesus, shed some light on me.. I am unable to figure out exact problem without any valid code..

Comment: I would recommend to share the code with us, so we can look at it on physical IE10. Also, you might use browserstack. It's 3 months free on http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools which has chrome plug-in.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to the site; I figured it would be easier to diagnose if someone else could just inspect it in their own copy of IE10. It happens all over the site, and inconsistently, so it's difficult for me to pull out specific pieces of HTML/CSS to reproduce it.

Comment: interestingly enough on Parallels Windows 8 Chrome gets all jacked up for me (screen goes black) and then IE10 displays OK, so it wouldn't be consistent as each browser may have a different rendering engine. Parallels does some weird things in my VMs at times (not that is it/is not related here, just to put it out there) I'll check the link out

Comment: I had some wierd artifacts when scrolling fast on overflow-y on an element in IE10 (for something else). All other browsers were fine. If I added 'z-index: 1'; to the container, it fixed the artifact issue for me. I am on Vmware/win7/IE10 on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong with the login, however I do notice an artifact that shows up IE10 on my desktop (which is not a powerful machine by any means)

Ironically when checking it out in parallels, that same artifact doesn't show up.
[image]

if you can narrow down a consistent test case we can check it out but in this case my 'answer' is going to be it's simply a virtual artifact. I would test out the other one I showed though, but oddly enough didn't show up on a VM.

Two guys from our team people together some great docs on getting VMs setup on Mac for the other technologies (VMware Fusion and VirtualBox) maybe give those a try as well.

[Setting up Win8/VMware Fusion on a Mac](http://aka.ms/virtualboxmac)

[Setting up Win8/VMware Fusion on a Mac](http://aka.ms/fusionmac)

[Setting up Win8/Parallels on a Mac](http://aka.ms/parallelsmac)

There is also this amazing site for testing how your browser looks - I'd run it there and check all the resulting images

http://browsershots.org/

Comment: That's strange. It looks like you have your zoom level up a bit based on those screenshots. Do you still see the artifacts at 100%? The artifacts are consistent for me, but I only have Windows 8 installed in Parallels, so I can't be sure that it isn't just something weird that Parallels is doing.

Comment: You could grab a trial of VMware and convert your parallels drive . I was at 100% scaling on that btw but not best monitor resolution